Upload a file from local drive to Sharepoint Onpremise
I am looking for a way to program an auto upload of any files in a folder (ex : c:/folder/file.txt) to Sharepoint Library.
I have a Sharepoint 2019 OnPremise.
Is there a way to do it with the API or PowerShell ?
I am not looking for a Power Automate solution, thank you.

You could use following PowerShell to upload files in the SharePoint 2019.
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Function to Upload File
Function Upload-AllFilesFromDir($WebURL, $DocLibName, $FolderPath)
{
    #Get the Web and List to upload the filen 
    $web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
       
    #Get the Target Document Library to upload
    $List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)
  
    #Get the Files from Local Folder
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath #You can filter files by: -filter “*.pdf”
 
    #upload the files
    Foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
        #Get the Contents of the file to FileStream
        $stream = (Get-Item $file.FullName).OpenRead()
     
        # Set Metadata Hashtable For the file - OPTIONAL
        $Metadata = @{"Country" = "United States"; "Domain" = "Sales"}
     
        #upload the file             
        $uploaded = $List.Files.Add($File.Name, $stream, $Metadata, $TRUE)
     
        #dispose FileStream Object
        $stream.Dispose()
    }
}
   
#call the upload function
Upload-AllFilesFromDir "https://SharePoint/sites/sales/" "Shared Documents" "C:\Documents\"


PowerShell Script:
To begin, you need the SharePoint Online Management Shell installed on your machine.
Step #3: Start PowerShell and Connection to your SharePoint Website
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://your-sharepoint-site-url" -UseWebLogin
Replace https://your-sharepoint-site-url with your url of the SharePoint site.
Below is the typscript that is used to Upload files from a folder at the local machine to SharePoint Library:
#Tells our local folder path.
$localFolderPath = "C:\folder"
#Specify the SharePoint Library Name
$libraryName = "YourLibraryName";
#Extract all files from the local folder
$files= Get-ChildItem -path $localFolderPath
Upload each of the the files to the SharePoint library
foreach ($item in $files) {
Add-PnPFile -Path $item. FullName -Folder $libraryName
}
Put your actual SharePoint library name instead of YourLibraryName
Just execute the script, it will upload

Thank you for your answer but I'm using Sharepoint 2019 :(
